# Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices equivalent with ASP.NET WebForms project

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I'm currently using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices library in an ASP.NET Core app to mix React and ASP.NET seamlessly, using Webpack and HMR. Is there an equivalent for the classic .NET Framework? I'd love to start introducing React in a legacy ASP.NET Webforms app without relying on Visual Studio Extensions to re-build the react app on save, and enabling HMR.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not. However, according to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/7911), you should be able to use SpaServices in an ASP.NET Core project *targeting* .NET Framework.